# How to resolve multiple RequireJS config files from Webjars

Tags: javascript, spring, requirejs, webjars

In a **spring-boot** application i obtained several **webjars** (basically javascript,css and resource files in jar packages), all which are specified in a maven pom file.

### pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>requirejs</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
        <version>${angularjs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

Spring-boot helps by exposing each script path. For example bootstrap is available using

`webjars/bootstrap/bootstrap-version/bootstrap.js`

Ok this is pretty cool i can now obtain each script in my html and js files.

But here's the thing, each of those webjars has it's own **webjars-requirejs.js** file with configs for module exposure and path and dependencies resolution.

I believe it's purpose is to be used, and not copied in some users custom require.config

### webjars/bootstrap/version/webjars-requirejs.js

```
/*global requirejs */

// Ensure any request for this webjar brings in jQuery.
requirejs.config({
paths: { 
    "bootstrap": webjars.path("bootstrap", "js/bootstrap"),
    "bootstrap-css": webjars.path("bootstrap", "css/bootstrap")  
  },
  shim: { "bootstrap": [ "jquery" ] }
});
```

### Question

Noticing the `webjars.path()` method i can't figure it's scope and how it will get resolved if i obtain several **webjars-requirejs.js** files with their `require.config()` from my own custom `require.config()`.
How can i manipulate those **webjars-requirejs.js** files in one custom javascript file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `webjars-requirejs.js` files are legacy artifacts.  The newer RequireJS metadata is in the WebJar's `pom.xml` file.  The `webjars-locator` library has some RequireJS utilities that make it easy to work with this metadata.  The [WebJar Docs](http://www.webjars.org/documentation) include some details on how to use this.

Comment: Thanks @James, answer came directly from the source :) I'll check out `webjars-locator` to see what it has to offer, even without some higher utility tools this is pretty amazing so far. I'll write some kind of tutorial after i set things up using `maven` and `gradle` in `spring boot` project to contribute with another usage specific example. Outstanding work man...

Comment: Thanks!  Would love any contributions you could make to the docs.  It would be great to have more working sample apps and guides.

Comment: I'll be glad to contribute, will contact you soon.